# Can't validate dropdown on bootstrap

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I am trying to validate the dropdown I have using bootstrap but nothing works. I've tried using , data-validation, etc and nothing works...

The other validation fields are working, but the dropdown is the only one I can use a validation to require someone to choose something from the list.

Anyone have a clue?

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">

                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <select required  class="form-control" id="tipo" name="tipoIn" >
                                    <option disabled selected>Tipo de imóvel</option>
                                    <option value="Moradia">Moradia</option>
                                    <option value="Apartamento">Apartamento</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <select required class="form-control" id="tipologia" name="Tipologia_input">
                                        <option disabled selected>Tipologia</option>
                                        <option value="T1">T1</option>
                                        <option value="T2">T2</option>
                                        <option value="T3">T3</option>
                                        <option value="T4">T4</option>
                                        <option value="T5">T5</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>


                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Completo" name="Nome" required="true">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" required="true">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" name="Telefone" required="true">
                              </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comentario" placeholder="Diga-nos como imagina a sua casa..." name="message"></textarea>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="button-slider">
                                  <div class="btn-group btn_group">
                                    <div class="btn btn-default btn_amount">Valor </div>
                                    <div class="btn btn-default btn_slider">
                                      <input id="bootstrap-slider" type="text" data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="50000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="25000" name="slider_value" />
                                      <div class="valueLabel"><span class="text_span">Valor &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="sliderValue">25000</span>€</div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default quote_btn">Enviar</button>
                            </form>
```

Comment: What type of validation do u want client side or server side??

Comment: Client side. I just want them to choose anything. :)

Comment: You can use simple jquery for this..

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP if you're only looking for client side actions? Not to mention, how about actual code to show what you've tried doing.

Comment: Using any validator plugin or pure jQuery? Also please post your JS code.

Comment: The other fields I just need to enter 'required="true" ', I just want the same for the dropdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please include `value=""` to the first disabled drop-down option for both the  `select` elements. The `required` attribute looks for blank value for validation.

From:

```
<option disabled selected>Tipo de imóvel</option>
```

to

```
<option disabled selected value="">Tipo de imóvel</option>
```

Comment: Thank you !! WORKED